# AWS DMS validation fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, dms

I migrated data from SQL Server database to Aurora Postgres, using AWS DMS. Everything works and data is migrated correctly, but then validation fails. There are two types of validation errors:

1. GUIDS in the source database are all uppercase and in the target: lowercase.

   {'record_id': 'DA7D98E2-06EA-4C3E-A148-3215E1C23384'}
   {'record_id': 'da7d98e2-06ea-4c3e-a148-3215e1c23384'}
2. For some reason, validation fails between timestamp(4) column in Postgres and datetime2(4) column of SQLServer. It seems like the time in Postgres has two extra 0's at the end, but when selecting data from the table normally, the data is exactly the same.
   {'created_datetime_utc': '2018-08-24 19:58:28.4900'}
   {'created_datetime_utc': '2018-08-24 19:58:28.490000'}

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to create transformation rules for columns, but they do not work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this article https://www.sentiatechblog.com/aws-database-migration-service-dms-tips-and-tricks, these new mapping rules fixed all validation issues. These rules cannot be added using AWS Console, only in the script.

[image]